# Missing buffer values when using zonal statistics in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, buffer, zonal-statistics

I am using zonal statistics in ArcGis 10.2.2 to calculate the mean value of fire frequency within 1km buffers. However, I have noticed that this is not being calculated for all of my sites.  There are a few overlapping buffers in my dataset.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: We need more information about your data to help you. Screenshots, maybe data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove overlaps and zonal statistics  will perform  as expected.

Extract from tool help:

> If the zone feature input has overlapping polygons, the zonal analysis
>   will not be performed for each individual polygon. Since the feature
>   input is converted to a raster, each location can only have one value.
>
> An alternative method is to process the zonal statistics iteratively
>   for each of the polygon zones and collate the results.

Comment: To compliment this answer if you were to iterate over each polygon then this can be easily done in model builder using a Feature Selection iterator feeding into the zonal stats tool.